# Detect, prevent downloading file in iframe & show message to download

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I'm using an iframe to preview browser supported content for different files using ReactJS, and have a download button below the iframe tag to download that file. I want to prevent downloading of file from iframe until the user clicks on download button & show a message in iframe tag that "file preview is not available, please download the file to view in your system.". a sample screenshot is attached.

[image]

Comment: You can use the frame load event

Comment: how to prevent download dialogue using onLoad event?